# Numbering solutions in exam environment

Tags: exam

I created my desired document using the exam environment. I have questions and solutions. One the first pages I have my questions, and on the last pages I have the solutions using the command `\SolutionsAtEnd`. What I want to know is how do I edit the "solution" environment so that I have my Solutions numbered: Solution 1, Soulution 2, etc.

Comment: as always could you provide a MWE?
The desired command should look somehow like this: `\newcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Solution \thequestion:}}`

Comment: It gives me an error. "Undefined control sequence"

Comment: What kind of Undefined control sequence do you get? I can't find `\SolutionsAtEnd` in the `exam` manual

Comment: I am so sorry. I used the quiz* enviroment. Here are the packages i used
'\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[dvipdfm,tight,designi]{web}
\usepackage{exerquiz}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{moresize}
\definecolor{mojaboja}{rgb}{0.85,0.60,0.90}
\definecolor{BojaZaZadatke}{rgb}{0.50,0.50,0.50}'

Comment: please add this to your question as a minimal working example. with some sample questions and answers. looks like, your not using `exam` at all.